# How can we say the Torah uses words of later-day languages?

Tags: history, language

My friend told me how the word *das,* which we use to mean halacha or religion, like *k'das Moshe veYisroel,* is actually a Persian word. If this is true, then how can commentators explain the word *aishdas* in [Vezos haBracha](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm#2) as meaning a fiery law, if Persia and Persian did not exist at the time of the Torah?
The same question goes for any similar instance in Tanach, if there are any.

Here are some sources about *das* being of Persian origin. Perhaps there are some more reliable sources too.

https://www.abarim-publications.com/Dictionary/d/d-ta.html

https://www.balashon.com/2006/03/dat.html

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%AA

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you know that the Persian language (or a predecessor) did not exist then?

Comment: Hebrew is a Semitic language. A whole host of words are similar if you look at comparisons with other texts of Semitic origin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_languages

Comment: Drush != Peshat